# How many hours after <drinking> <I drink> Can I drive?

Tags: meaning

> How many hours after drinking Can I drive?

> How many hours after I drink Can I drive?

Which sentence would be better? Should I use verb+ing or full sentence after “how many hours after”? Are all sentence correct?

Comment: No capital letter for "can", it doesn't start a sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Both these forms are correct.  "After" can function as a preposition: "after drinking" and as a conjunction: "After I drink".

The meaning is (in this case) the same.  The preposition form "after drinking" is (according to ngrams) much more common.